# How does foursquare app on iOS auto log me in?

Tags: ios, authentication, foursquare

Background: I was looking for a good copy for my app to use facebook login.

I searched for top apps which uses fb login and foursquare was one of them. I haven't use the app in a while. I downloaded it again and click open. They have updated the app and displays a series of screens about new tutorials and features. At the end of it, it automatically log me in and knows who I am. I'm confused about this. I did not click on any 'login with facebook' or enter any credentials.

I also went to www.foursquare.com and after a few seconds, the website reloads and logs me in. The profile is the same as my iOS one.

Another detail that interest me is that the email address I use for foursquare is not the same as my facebook one. I check my fb apps and foursquare is not listed there so there is no connection between fb and foursquare in my limited knowledge.

I deleted the app, reinstall, and open it and it immediately know who I am.

How does it work?

Thanks,

Comment: this question is probably better suited for a foursquare forum

Comment: Do you have your Facebook account signed in on your phone? Facebook and Twitter are now device-wide logins instead of on a per-app basis.

Comment: @mgrenier I'm trying to replicate this if I can so it's not limited to just foursquare. I'm thinking it has something to do with the iOS SDK